# Can anyone explain what is private readonly IStudentRepository _studentRepository? why is it taken?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-4, inversion-of-control

There are two files: one giving the interface as follows:

IStudentInterface.cs

```
 public interface IStudentService
{
    IEnumerable<Student> GetStudents();
    Student GetStudentById(int id);
    void CreateStudent(Student student);
    void UpdateStudent(Student student);
    void DeleteStudent(int id);
    void SaveStudent();
}
```

StudentService.cs:

```
 public class StudentService : IStudentService
  {
    private readonly IStudentRepository _studentRepository;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    public StudentService(IStudentRepository studentRepository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this._studentRepository = studentRepository;
        this._unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }  
    #region IStudentService Members

    public IEnumerable<Student> GetStudents()
    {
        var students = _studentRepository.GetAll();
        return students;
    }

    public Student GetStudentById(int id)
    {
        var student = _studentRepository.GetById(id);
        return student;
    }

    public void CreateStudent(Student student)
    {
        _studentRepository.Add(student);
        _unitOfWork.Commit();
    }

    public void DeleteStudent(int id)
    {
        var student = _studentRepository.GetById(id);
        _studentRepository.Delete(student);
        _unitOfWork.Commit();
    }

    public void UpdateStudent(Student student)
    {
        _studentRepository.Update(student);
        _unitOfWork.Commit();
    }

    public void SaveStudent()
    {
        _unitOfWork.Commit();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Please, explain me why the private `_studentRepository` variable is created? We could also be able to do our task instead of it. Why all these things are done like this way? Please explain me this concept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IStudentRepository` is a set of functionality (a contract, an abstraction, a service - it can go by various terms) that the `StudentService` object depends on to perform its work. The `StudentService` also depends on `IUnitOfWork` to perform its work.

`private readonly IStudentRepository _studentRepository;` is a variable declaration to store an instance of an object that implements the contract. It is private because it is only needed to be accessed within the `StudentService` class and it is readonly because it is set in the constructor of the class and does not need to be modified later in the lifetime of any `StudentService' instance.

The concept of inversion of control is that instead of the `StudentService` being responsible for locating the implementations of its dependencies and instantiating them and managing their lifetime, some other code external to `StudentService` takes those responsibilities. This is desirable because it reduces the concerns of the `StudentService` class.

In order to make applying inversion of control easier, a container is often used. A container provides a way of saying which implementations should be used for an interface or contract, and also provides a mechanism for automatically providing those implementations. The most common way is through constructor injection. The IoC container will create the `StudentService` class and it will also create the dependencies needed to construct it. In the constructor you would store the dependency objects in class-level variables so they can be used to perform work when a method is called.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer of qes is very clear!

IStudentService is an interface, it does not contain concrete methods, just defines what implementations must have and must do.

The class StudentService is the implementation, you already know you need to have the methods Create, Update, Delete and Save because they're in the interface. So you will find this concrete methods in this class.

_studentRepository is a field, not a property so you don't want anyone else to touch it and that's why it is private. But is also readonly because it needs to be defined when you initialize the StudentServices class and it needs to remain as when the object was created.

I hope this answer complements the previous one.